# On behalf of the government & the people of . .

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is there anything wrong with the following Tweet? It's understood that the person who offered her good wishes is the leader of a country. I'm wondering whether there's a contradiction involved, since I suppose the "on behalf of" implies that she is not a member of the government.

> On behalf of the government & the people of Taiwan, wishing @POTUS & @FLOTUS a swift recovery.

Comment: In some countries the term "government" is conventionally used in a way that excludes the head of state, but even if that isn't the case in Taiwan, I don't think "on behalf of X" means that the speaker isn't a part of X. I think a company boss can write "on behalf of [company]" without implying that he doesn't share that view or isn't part of the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly normal usage.

[Merriam-Webster "on behalf of"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20behalf%20of)
as a representative of

While she is a member of both the government and the people of Taiwan, she is speaking as their representative.